# Wrong number of arguments in flow pattern

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog

so i created this simple AI code and i want to add a simple multiply math to my code so its done like this

```
domains
bonus = integer

predicates
crew_db(string, integer, string) - nondeterm (o,o,o)
absensi_crew(string, symbol) - nondeterm (o,o), (i,i)
posisi_terdaftar(string, symbol) - nondeterm (o,o), (i,i)
terima_gaji(string) - nondeterm (o,i,i,o)
tambah_bonus(bonus,bonus,bonus) - procedure (i,i,o)

clauses
crew_db("Muhammad", 18, "Bantaeng, 28 November 1998").
crew_db("Irvan", 20, "Bantaeng, 28 November 1998").
crew_db("Jaya", 21, "Bantaeng, 28 November 1998").

absensi_crew("Muhammad",aman).
absensi_crew("Irvan",aman).
absensi_crew("Jaya",tidak).

posisi_terdaftar("Muhammad",aktif).
posisi_terdaftar("Irvan",aktif).
posisi_terdaftar("Jaya",tidak).

terima_gaji(TesBebasTernyata):-
  crew_db(TesBebasTernyata,_,_),
  absensi_crew(TesBebasTernyata,aman),
  posisi_terdaftar(TesBebasTernyata,aktif).

tambah_bonus(A,B,Bonus):-
  Bonus=A*B.

goal
terima_gaji(Crew_Yang_Di_Gaji_Bulan_Ini),tambah_bonus(45000,2,Bonus).
```

and when i check the goals of my Prolog, it fails and said wrong number of arguments in flow pattern

Comment: Which Prolog system are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In clause

```
terima_gaji(TesBebasTernyata):-
  crew_db(TesBebasTernyata,_,_),
  absensi_crew(TesBebasTernyata,aman),
  posisi_terdaftar(TesBebasTernyata,aktif).
```

you have

```
crew_db(TesBebasTernyata,_,_)
```

but your facts are

```
crew_db("Muhammad", 18, "Bantaeng, 28 November 1998").
crew_db("Irvan", 20, "Bantaeng, 28 November 1998").
crew_db("Jaya", 21, "Bantaeng, 28 November 1998").
```

Notice that the clauses has three argument positions while your facts have four.

Change

```
crew_db(TesBebasTernyata,_,_)
```

to

```
crew_db(TesBebasTernyata,_,_,_)
```

Since I do not have Visual Prolog I can not test this answer with Visual Prolog.

Comment: im new at prolog :D

Comment: @IrvanJaya You can accept this as an answer by click on the check mark to the left of this answer and also give it an up-vote by clicking on the upward pointing triangle. :)